# Why doesn't removing the Ice Crown have any effect?

Tags: adventure-time

In the *Adventure Time* season five episode, "The Party's Over, Isla de Señorita," the Ice King spends a significant portion of the episode powerless because he isn't wearing his crown. This is expected and consistent with established canon.

However, in the earlier episode "Simon & Marcy," we see:

> When Simon removes the Ice Crown, he reverts to a milder version of himself, the hippie version who cares about Marceline and remembers the Time Before the Mushroom War. We know (thanks to that same episode) that the power of the crown increases dramatically each time Simon uses it.

However, why doesn't removing the crown do this anymore?

Answer (score 5):

During the episode "Simon & Marcy":

> Marcy mentions that Simon's features have changed each time he takes the crown off. Simon is very reluctant throughout the episode to put the Ice Crown on, because each time it becomes harder and harder for him take off again and each time he puts it on he keeps a little piece of the Ice King's features in his personality and the way he physically looks. At the end of the episode, the last time he puts the Ice Crown on, he sings a song that reminds him of his previous self. This is the only way he is able to come back to help save Marcy. If you notice that when he takes the Ice Crown off the final time in this episode, he barely resembles Simon at all and looks almost completely like the Ice King.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear Simon is slowly changing, his tapes have proven that; the best I can say is, at the end of "Simon and Marcy" Simon's skin is noticeably bluer than throughout the episode, and he calls Marceline "Gunter". This shows a gradual but permanent change; also, in the beginning, when he takes it on after putting it on the first time in the episode, he keeps his altered features, and still acts a bit psychotic for a few seconds, but reverts back to his normal self after a short time; therefore we can assume that after keeping the crown on for a longer time, its effects will stay in his body longer while the crown is not on his head.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be simply because each time he puts on his crown it leaves a little more of the ice king in his body so after putting the crown on so many times he eventually just got every bit of the ice king so that's who he is now its very sad to think about though. Sorry if that doesn't make sense lol.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  That does make sense; it makes enough sense that both of the other answers already say this.  Can you add anything to your answer to make it more complete?  Some screenshots showing Simon's progression to the Ice King would be great.